# how to display a keyboard automatically

Tags: android

When an activity is started, the keyboard should automatically get displayed without click of the edittext. I know that when we click the edittext, the keyboard is displayed. But I want that the keyboard should automatically get displayed. How to do this? Please reply.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` to your activity xml tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. More details can be found [in documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

```
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <application ...>
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" ... />
    </application>
    ...    
</manifest>
```

Comment: Do I need to write something in the corresponding activity Java file?